# Unexpected column values after the IN condition in where() method of dataframe in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

**Task:** I want the value of `child_id` column **`[Which is generated using withColumn()  method and monoliticallyIncreasingId() method]`** corresponding to `family_id` and `id` column.

Let me explain steps to complete my task:

**Step 1:** 1. adding 2 columns to the dataframe. 1 with unique id and named as child_id, and another with value 0 and named parent_id.

**Step 2:** need all family_ids from dataframe.

**Step 3:** want the dataframe of child_id and id, where id == family_id.
**[Problem is here.]**

```
def processFoHierarchical(param_df: DataFrame) {
    var dff = param_df.withColumn("child_id", monotonicallyIncreasingId() + 1)
    println("Something is not gud...")
    dff = dff.withColumn("parent_id", lit(0.toLong))
    dff.select("id","family_id","child_id").show() // Original dataframe.

    var family_ids = ""
    param_df.select("family_id").distinct().coalesce(1).collect().map(x => family_ids = family_ids + "'" + x.getAs[String]("family_id") + "',")
    println(family_ids)
    var x: DataFrame = null

    if (family_ids.length() > 0) {
      family_ids = family_ids.substring(0, family_ids.length() - 1) 
      val y = dff.where(" id IN (" + family_ids + ")").select("id","family_id","child_id") 
      y.show() // here i am getting unexpected values.
    }
```

This is the output of my code. I am trying to get the child_id values as per in dataframe. but i am not getting it.
**Note:** Using **`Spark`** with **`Scala`**.

```
+--------------------+--------------------+----------+
|                  id|           family_id|  child_id|
+--------------------+--------------------+----------+
|fe60c680-eb59-11e...|fe60c680-eb59-11e...|         4|
|8d9680a0-ec14-11e...|8d9680a0-ec14-11e...|         9|
|ff81457a-e9cf-11e...|ff81457a-e9cf-11e...|         5|
|4261cca0-f0e9-11e...|4261cca0-f0e9-11e...|        10|
|98c7dc00-f0e5-11e...|98c7dc00-f0e5-11e...|         8|
|dca16200-e462-11e...|dca16200-e462-11e...|8589934595|
|78be8950-ecca-11e...|ff81457a-e9cf-11e...|         1|
|4cc19690-e819-11e...|ff81457a-e9cf-11e...|         3|
|dca16200-e462-11e...|ff81457a-e9cf-11e...|8589934596|
|72dd0250-eff4-11e...|78be8950-ecca-11e...|         2|
|84ed0df0-e81a-11e...|78be8950-ecca-11e...|         6|
|78be8951-ecca-11e...|78be8950-ecca-11e...|         7|
|d1515310-e9ad-11e...|78be8951-ecca-11e...|8589934593|
|d1515310-e9ad-11e...|72dd0250-eff4-11e...|8589934594|
+--------------------+--------------------+----------+

'72dd0250-eff4-11e5-9ce9-5e5517507c66','dca16200-e462-11e5-90ec-c1cf090b354c','78be8951-ecca-11e5-a5f5-c1cf090b354c','4261cca0-f0e9-11e5-bbba-c1cf090b354c','98c7dc00-f0e5-11e5-bc76-c1cf090b354c','fe60c680-eb59-11e5-9582-c1cf090b354c','ff81457a-e9cf-11e5-9ce9-5e5517507c66','8d9680a0-ec14-11e5-a94f-c1cf090b354c','78be8950-ecca-11e5-a5f5-c1cf090b354c',
+--------------------+--------------------+-----------+
|                  id|           family_id|   child_id|
+--------------------+--------------------+-----------+
|fe60c680-eb59-11e...|fe60c680-eb59-11e...|          1|
|ff81457a-e9cf-11e...|ff81457a-e9cf-11e...|          2|
|98c7dc00-f0e5-11e...|98c7dc00-f0e5-11e...|          3|
|8d9680a0-ec14-11e...|8d9680a0-ec14-11e...|          4|
|4261cca0-f0e9-11e...|4261cca0-f0e9-11e...|          5|
|dca16200-e462-11e...|dca16200-e462-11e...|          6|
|78be8950-ecca-11e...|ff81457a-e9cf-11e...| 8589934593|
|dca16200-e462-11e...|ff81457a-e9cf-11e...| 8589934594|
|72dd0250-eff4-11e...|78be8950-ecca-11e...|17179869185|
|78be8951-ecca-11e...|78be8950-ecca-11e...|17179869186|
+--------------------+--------------------+-----------+
```

I know that it doesn't produce consecutive values, those values are dependents on partitions. Unexpected values means (see 2nd dataframe) those child_ids are meant to belong from the previous dataframe where family_id = id and to match multiple ids i am using IN. Unexpected values here means the child_id column have no values from the above dataframe instead it is creating new child_id column with monoliticallyIncresingIds().

See the last 2 values in 2nd dataframe doesn't belong to the above dataframe. So where does it coming from. I am not applying `monoliticallyIncresingIds()` again on dataframe. So, why it looks like that column (child_id) having the values like  `monoliticallyIncresingIds()` is applied again.

Comment: Why are these "unexpected values"? What are the _expected_ values? Note that `monoliticallyIncreasingId` doesn't necessarily create _consecutive_ values, so these "jumps" from ~6 to ~8 Billion does _not_ mean 8 Billion records were skipped. See https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/expressions/MonotonicallyIncreasingID.scala#L28

Comment: I know that it doesn't produce consecutive values, those values are dependents on partitions. Unexpected values means (see 2nd dataframe) those child_ids are meant to belong from the previous dataframe where family_id = id and to match multiple ids i am using IN. Unexpected values here means the child_id column have no values from the above dataframe instead it is creating new child_id column with `monoliticallyIncresingIds()`.

Comment: can anyone suggest me what kind of info I am supposed to add for clarification on the question. so, it can be considered or re-opened. Or you can suggest me what you didn't getting.. I will add explanation in my question as i recently did.

Comment: First - make this a _minimal, reproducable_ example (see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve): keep only the relevant columns, remove unrelated columns, so that readers can easily create a working example to test on their environments. Second - verify what the unexpected values are - if I understand correctly (now) - your actual question is something like "Where do values like `17179869185` in the result's child_id column come from, if they don't exist in the intermediary printed result?"

Comment: Thank you for respond@Tzach Zohar. As per your suggestion i removed the unnecessary columns from first dataframe. And ya, now you got it. My concern is, Those 2 values `17179869185 , 17179869186`, where they came from? and 2nd the other values are not what as they are expected.  I mean just have a look at above dataframe other child ids are also irrelevant. Its look like the `monoliticallyIncresingId()` method has applied again. and those last 2 values are different because it isn't residing in same partition as others .(as far as I can understand.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

However, The problem is not with spark **DataFrame** . When we are using **monoliticallyIncresingId()** with DataFrame, it will create new id for each time on **DataFrame.show()**.

if we need to generate id once and needs to refer same id at other place in code then we may need to **DataFrame.cache()**.

In your case, you need to cache DataFrame after **Step1**  so it will not create duplicate **child_id** every time on **show()**.

Comment: Well, What you are saying is correct as i tested it. But i couldn't get it. How and why it is actually occurring ?   By the way Thanxx.. @Uttam Kasundara